# KeyError: 0 when try to access a row in pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I am following a book Hands on machine learning with scikit-learn to learn machine learning
and following is the code to get display an MNIST image but I get a `keyError 0` when I try to index a single image from the dataset.

```
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_openml

mnist = fetch_openml('mnist_784', version=1)

X, y = mnist["data"], mnist["target"]

some_digit = X[0]
```

Below is the error I get when I run the cell in jupyter notebook.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
File ~\anaconda3\anaconda-py\envs\data-science\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py:3621, in Index.get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3620 try:
-> 3621     return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3622 except KeyError as err:

File ~\anaconda3\anaconda-py\envs\data-science\lib\site-packages\pandas\_libs\index.pyx:136, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

File ~\anaconda3\anaconda-py\envs\data-science\lib\site-packages\pandas\_libs\index.pyx:163, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

File pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi:5198, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

File pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi:5206, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 0

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [10], in <cell line: 3>()
      1 import matplotlib as mpl
      2 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
----> 3 some_digit = X[0]
      4 some_digit_image = some_digit.reshape(28, 28)
      5 plt.imshow(some_digit_image, cmap = mpl.cm.binary, interpolation="nearest")

File ~\anaconda3\anaconda-py\envs\data-science\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py:3505, in DataFrame.__getitem__(self, key)
   3503 if self.columns.nlevels > 1:
   3504     return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
-> 3505 indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
   3506 if is_integer(indexer):
   3507     indexer = [indexer]

File ~\anaconda3\anaconda-py\envs\data-science\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py:3623, in Index.get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3621     return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3622 except KeyError as err:
-> 3623     raise KeyError(key) from err
   3624 except TypeError:
   3625     # If we have a listlike key, _check_indexing_error will raise
   3626     #  InvalidIndexError. Otherwise we fall through and re-raise
   3627     #  the TypeError.
   3628     self._check_indexing_error(key)

KeyError: 0
```

Answer (score 6):

This tries to access a column called `0`:

```py
df[0]
```

which your dataframe doesn't have, hence the `KeyError`.

To access a row of a dataframe by its index, you have to use:

```py
df.loc[0]

# or

df.iloc[0]
```

which one depends on the dataframe's index values and also the exact thing you want to accomplish. They can also be used to specify columns.

Answer (score 0):

I faced with the same error when following the book.
I used @baileythegreen answer to make it work.

All you need is to assign `X.loc[0].array` to `some_digit`.

```
some_digit = X.loc[0].array
```

Then the rest of the code will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

## try this instead

some_digit = X.values[0]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).